# Alternate colors on click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm sure there is a simple solution to this, and I'm sure this is a duplicate question, though I have been unable to solve my solution particularly because I don't really know how to phrase it in order to search for other questions/solutions, so I'm coming here hoping for some help.

Basically, I have `span`s with classes that assigns a `background-color` property, and inside those `span`s are words. I have three of these spans, and each time a user clicks on a span I want the class to change (thus changing the background color and inner text).

**HTML:**

```
<span class="alternate">
    <span class="blue showing">Lorem</span>
    <span class="green">Ipsum</span>
    <span class="red">Dolor</span>
</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
.alternate span { display : none }
.alternate .showing { display : inline }
.blue { background : blue }
.green { background : green }
.red { background : red }
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".alternate span").each(function() {
    $(this).on("click", function() {
        $(this).removeClass("showing");
        $(this).next().addClass("showing");
    });
});
```

This solution works great using `$.next` until I get to the third click, whereafter `.showing` is removed, and is not added since there are no more `$.next` options. How do I, after getting to the `last-child`, add `.showing` to the `first-child` and then start over? I have tried various options including `if($(".alternate span:last-child").hasClass("showing")) { etc. etc. }`, and I attempted to use an `array` and `for loop` though I failed to make it work.

Newb question, I know, but I can't seem to solve this so as a last resort I'm coming here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$(".alternate span").each(function() {
   $(this).on("click", function() {
        $(this).removeClass("showing");

        if($(this).is(":last-child"))
            $(".alternate span:first-child").addClass("showing");
        else
            $(this).next().addClass("showing");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NPx2x/

Comment: Thanks! This worked. This is actually similar to what I tried before but I guess I did something wrong somewhere. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Check this, and also it performs faster. `.next()` returns undefined if no element found.

```
$(".alternate span").on("click", function() {

    $(this).removeClass("showing");
     var next = $(this).next();

     next.length ? next.addClass("showing") : $("span.blue").addClass("showing");    
});
```